# Access child component from parent component

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an header component and registration component and a login component.
The selector of header component is used in both login component and registration component.  And there is a button in the header . It will shown as login button if the user is in the url .../registration .  And on clicking that button Route will change to login

```
this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
```

​I want to change that button into 'Registration', when the user move to login page. How can I control that button from login component and registration component.

Comment: You can use `EventEmitter`.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished it using ***`@Input`*** API.

***Boot.ts***

```
import {Component,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,APP_BASE_HREF,LocationStrategy,RouteParams,ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router';
import {bootstrap}  from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import{ComponentOne} from 'src/cone';
import{ComponentTwo} from 'src/ctwo';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Component Router</h1>
    <nav>
    <hr>
      <a [routerLink]="['ComponentOne']">Login</a><hr/>
      <a [routerLink]="['ComponentTwo']">Registartion</a>
    </nav>
    <hr>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/component-one', name: 'ComponentOne', component: ComponentOne useAsDefault:true},
  {path:'/component-two', name: 'ComponentTwo', component: ComponentTwo}
])
export class AppComponent { }

    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS,bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)
    ]);
```

***Login.ts OR cone.ts***

```
 import {Component,View,ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
 import {HeaderCmp} from 'src/header';


 @Component({
    template: `

    <header text="Registration"></header>
    <hr>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    `,
    directives:[HeaderCmp] 
  })

  export class ComponentOne {

      constructor(){ 
             console.log("first component being called");
      }

  }
```

***Registartion.ts OR ctwo.ts***

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
 import {HeaderCmp} from 'src/header';

 @Component({
    template: `
    <header text="Login"></header>
    <h1>Registration </h1>
    `,
    directives:[HeaderCmp]
  })

  export class ComponentTwo{
    constructor(){

      console.log("Second component being called");
    }
  }
```

***Header.ts***

```
import {Component,View,Input} from 'angular2/core';
 import {sharedService} from 'src/sharedService';

 @Component({
   selector:'header',
    template: `
    <h4>Header </h4>
    <button>{{text}}</button>
    `
  })

  export class HeaderCmp{
     @Input() text: string='myText';

      constructor(){
               console.log("Header being called");
      }

 }
```

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEUkPORKOL9yzWby5KrN?p=preview)**